# Had to upgrade Postgres on Ubuntu; now, how to access old, missing databases?

Tags: postgresql

My local connection on my Ubuntu server (14.04) wasn't working to my Postgres (9.3) database, so I tried upgrading it to 9.4 to solve the connection issues. Luckily I can now connect to the database, but... My old databases (and tables, views, etc.) are now missing...

Is it possible to recover these? How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've removed the old 9.3 cluster there should be 2 clusters running:

```
$ service postgresql status
9.3/main (port 5432): online
9.4/main (port 5433): online
```

(or use `pg_lsclusters` to display existing PostgreSQL clusters).

PostgresSQL commands accepts `-p` argument to distinguish which DB cluster you're using (it accepts also Unix socket path). You can export old data using (assuming that the old DB runs on port `5432`):

```
su - postgres
pg_dump -p 5432 my_db -f my_db.dump
# import data into new DB cluster
pg_restore -p 5433 -d my_db my_db.dump
```

Answer (score -1):

Unless you have a backup dump lying around, the safest way to do this is to:

- uninstall Postgres 9.4,
- install 9.3,
- backup the database using `pg_dumpall > backup.sql`,
- uninstall Postgres 9.3,
- install Postgres 9.4,
- restore the databases using `psql -d postgres -f backup.sql`.

The 9.3 databases are in a different format than what 9.4 expects and there is no easy way to convert them using 9.4 tools only.

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling Postgres 9.4 is really not necessary.